# Use Or operator (|) as separator in character string

Tags: r

I want to know how to use the Or operator when I collapse a vector into a single string.  Also, understanding why R will not output the expected results using this piece of code will be helpful.  This will be used as the pattern in a grepl() command in a later piece of code.

```
vec = c("this", "that", "the other thing")
paste(vec, sep = "|", collapse = "")
```

This paste doesn't work as expected, only returning a string "thisthatthe other thing".  The result should be "this|that|the other thing".

I have also tried using escape characters:

```
paste(vec, sep = "/|", collapse = "")
paste(vec, sep = "\|", collapse = "")
paste(vec, sep = "/||", collapse = "")
```

But none of these have achieved the desired results.

Comment: `paste(vec, collapse = "|")`. See `?paste` and the difference between the `sep` and `collapse` arguments.

Comment: Learn from `paste(vec, vec, sep = "|", collapse = "&")`

Comment: You need to understand the use of `...`. `paste` can take more than one argument to paste together. You could do for instance `paste("this","that","the other thing" , sep = "|" , collapse="")`.